# Pagination in RDLC reports in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, rdlc

I am working in RDLC reports.I have to work on 65000 record and it takes about 5 to 6 minute in processing.After that I just assign this dataset to reports. During this time  user can  do nothing but wait.

Is there any option that I show the 10 records per page and when user navigate to next page I work on next 10 records and show them in page.So application will be more responsive.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using asynchronous programming or using BackgroundWorker? They will provide you more responsive UI while doing blocking process, including long running computations.

Both of them are having their own advantages and disadvantages.

Using async programming in WPF is quite difficult using BeginInvoke and EndInvoke model and callback (although it's simplified in future release of C# 5/ VB 11 async programming). But using this model, you'll simply using context switcher of a thread.

Using BackgroundWorker, this means spawning a new thread running in background.

For more information about async programming in .NET using event programming model:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx

This is the reference of BackgroundWorker:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: If i use another thread then i have to also wait until thread completes its execution.Indeed user can do some thing other with application but can not see the report instantly.But my requirement is i load the report with 10 records(Instantly) as user navigate to next page i get a new record and attach it to page and show to user.

Comment: To see the report you can have a progress bar that gets updated in the callback of a BackgroundWorker or in an async callback.

Comment: for those who downvote this answer, could you please explain why?